# What is the equivalent method in Angular 2 of Angular $.grep() method?

Tags: javascript, angular, grep

How can I refactor this code using angular 2 methods? I could not find anything on google.

```
var tooltipsData = $.grep(tooltips, function (element, index) {
    return (element.ProductCode == ProductCode);
});
```

Comment: I don't know Angular1. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like what you really are trying to do is implement that without jQuery (Angular 2 is still just JavaScript (or TypeScript)).
If you are trying to implement it in JS, use the [Array.filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var tooltipsData = tooltips.filter(function (element, index) {
   return (element.ProductCode === ProductCode);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This should work. I like that it uses a JS bulit in method.

Comment: Could be a non-issue but thought it was worth mentioning the browser support only goes back to IE9 for the filter function.

Answer (score 2):

Angular1 with Jquery:

```
var tooltipsData = $.grep(tooltips, function (element, index) {
        return (element.ProductCode == ProductCode);
  });
```

Angular2:

```
this.tooltipsData = tooltips.forEach((element, index)=>{
   return (element.ProductCode == ProductCode);
});
```

You can also use

```
this.tooltipsData = tooltips.filter((element, index) => {
   return (element.ProductCode == ProductCode);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I like the use of lambda function. I'm still getting used to them.

Comment: `forEach` always returns undefined, therefore using it in that manner will not solve the problem as tooltipsData will always be `undefined`

Comment: What do you mean by always undefined?

Comment: If I use `forEach` I must declare the output array ahead of the operation. filter does it in one step. Convenience.

Comment: Downvoting doesnt make any sense here.

Comment: @Adrian if you are using Typescript, you should follow lambda/arrow function.

Comment: from MDN Array.forEach documentation.
"forEach() executes the callback function once for each array element; unlike map() or reduce() it always returns the value undefined and is not chainable. The typical use case is to execute side effects at the end of a chain."
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: My brother, that was not my final answer ,you should also see I have shown two ways.

Comment: Let's not get into discussion, your answer is already accepted and i dont know why...